# Python Requests requesting a different instagram link than it's supposed to

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, screen-scraping

I'm making a script that checks the availability of a username on Instagram. I've had a lot of problems with it but I found that my code isn't the issue (to my knowledge) but `requests` is going to a different link than what I tell it to. Here is the part of the code that sends the request:

```py
self.account_url=("https://www.instagram.com/" + self.usernameToTest + "/?__a=1/")
print(self.account_url)
r = requests.get(self.account_url)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)
print(r.status_code)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("[" + self.usernameToTest + " is taken.]")
else:
    if r.status_code == 404:
        print("[" + self.usernameToTest + " is AVAILABLE!]")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Error checking username: " + self.usernameToTest)
```

To sum it up, the variable `self.usernameToTest` is the username that is being tested, so if the username is `testusername`, the variable `self.account_url` will be: "`https://www.instagram.com/testusername/?__a=1`".

The link with `/?__a=1` is what I'm using to determine if the account is taken because it will return a 404 if it is. The issue I'm having is that when I run it, the request seems to be getting a status code 302 then redirecting to the link `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/` every time. This gives the status 200 so it says the username is taken every time. Example of the output when I run it:

```
https://www.instagram.com/koakodskodakwoaksodkwa/?__a=1/
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
[<Response [302]>]
200
[koakodskodakwoaksodkwa is taken.]
```

I can't figure out why its doing this because when I paste the link myself into chrome, it doesn't redirect and just gives me the site `https://www.instagram.com/koakodskodakwoaksodkwa/?__a=1/` with the status 404.
I think it may have something to do with my internet or something because for some reason, it wasn't working at first, but I had a vpn on and when I turned it off, it started working successfully but then later out of nowhere stopped working again. Also when I sent the code to others, it worked for them too. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm kind of inexperienced in coding and don't know much about requests on python so I don't know if its something I'm doing wrong, something with my internet, or something with Instagram, but I know its not the code because it works for other people and myself for a period of time.

Comment: Maybe you have some dns caching problems, If you are on windows try in powershell `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a workaround for this exact same problem for a while now. I believe it has to do with the cookies Instagram uses to ensure you're a real logged in user and not a random bot. Try logging into Instagram in your browser and then running the script from the same machine while logged in and see if that works.